# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in drawRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, compiler-errors, exc-bad-access

I have a UIView placed above a WebView. In this UIView I have to draw on but the app crashes with this error

in LibraryViewController.m

```
 self.drawView =[[DrawView alloc]init];
 self.drawView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
 self.drawView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
 self.drawView.alpha=0.5;

 [self.webView addSubview:self.drawView];
```

In DrawView.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface DrawView : UIView

 @end
```

In DrawView.m

```
@implementation DrawView
{
   UIImage *incrementalImage;
   //......
}

 - (void)eraseDrawing:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t
{
    incrementalImage = nil;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
         //.....
        [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        [offsetPath stroke]; // ................. (8)
        [offsetPath fill]; 
        incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [offsetPath removeAllPoints];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            bufIdx = 0;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
           });
       });
       //.....
  }

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
      [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect]; //Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xa000008)
 }
```

This application does not use ARC

Comment: You appear to be drawing *outside* of `drawRect`?

Comment: he drawing must take place when I move my finger on UIView

Comment: Then you invalidate the view to force a redraw, you don't just start drawing.  See `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Comment: Of what type is `incrementalImage`? Where is it instanciated? And what so you expect to happen here? All you do is you force some other object (probably a UIView subclass too?) to draw itself and you may force it into a rect that is probably not its own drawing area.

Comment: Is it correct to have `[incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];` there? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For draw freehand in ios there is a good example:

https://github.com/levinunnink/Smooth-Line-View

solved everything by using this example

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.photoEditView.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.photoEditView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.photoEditView.frame.size.width, self.photoEditView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGPathRelease(path);
self.photoEditView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code works for me (even on iOS 7).

Comment: With your solution I get error in **drawInRect**. The
error is similar to that of the first

Comment: With my solution You don't need to use drawInRect:. UIImageView draw image without any additions. You need only collect drawing from context and give it to it.

Comment: In your solution there is **drawInRect** at third line

Comment: Seems that You have error in Your memory management. Try to check is variables exist at moment when You try to draw.